# Go back to previous activity fast in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

In my android application, there is an activity to add a search keyword to the list. After adding a keyword, the user has to press the back button to go to the previous activity. In the previous activity I am getting data from the internet according to the keyword which I added. My problem is that when I pressed the back button it will take the same time to go to the previous activity. How can I speed up this process? My code:

```
goBack = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backbutton);
goBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    isBackPressed=true;
    finish();
}
```

Comment: you don't need to call finish if you called super.onBackPressed()

Answer (score 0):

You should store the stuff you get from the internet permanently so you don't get it every time you show the activity, that way it will load much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea, if you just need to enter some keyword, why don't you use a Dialog instead of a full blown activity? A dialog is much lighter and displays much much faster :)

It should look something like this-

[image]

For an example, try the DIALOG_TEXT_ENTRY dialog in the ALERT DIALOG sample API Demos here http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlertDialogSamples.html

Answer (score 0):

Is your previous activity downloading data from the internet in the main thread? If so, that is your problem. The activity you have shown is plenty fast, but your previous activity spends some time resuming (because of the internet download). This is bad for two reasons:

1. The responsiveness goes bad. If the user has a bad connection everything will freeze!
2. If the user is using a Honeycomb device (maybe also ICS, I haven't tried) it will throw an exception and either crash or (if you catch it) just fail to work.

Your solution is to do the download in a background thread, maybe with a dialog telling the user to please wait, showing the download progress if available.